# Android: Open and read another app location

Tags: java, android, kotlin, adb

I need to develop an app which monitors a list of apps and, if the system is rebooted, return to the last open page of the monitored apps. So, say that android was on the youtube app playing [lofi hip hop radio - beats to relax/study to](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5qap5aO4i9A&ab_channel=LofiGirl). How could my app send android back to this given video? Also, is there a way for me to know where in the app the user is? For example, can I know that the user was on youtube playing lofi and open it back again for them?

I already know how to open another app as well as detect whichever app is currently open, but I need to know the its uri as well. I can use adb and shell script if it is needed.

I have the following code to launch another app:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

        val intent = Intent(this, BackAppListenerService::class.java)
        startService(intent)

        openApp(this, "com.google.android.youtube")
    }

    /** Open another app.
     * @param context current Context, like Activity, App, or Service
     * @param packageName the full package name of the app to open
     * @return true if likely successful, false if unsuccessful
     */
    fun openApp(context: Context, packageName: String?): Boolean {
        val manager = context.packageManager
        return try {
            val i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName!!)
            if (i == null) {
                println("Activity not found")
                return false;
                //throw new ActivityNotFoundException();
            }
            //throw new ActivityNotFoundException();
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
            context.startActivity(i)
            true
        } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
            println(e)
            false
        }
    }

}
```

And with this I get the current foreground app

```kotlin
class BackAppListenerService  : Service() {
    private var isRunning = false
    private var lastApp = ""

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    override fun onCreate() {
        isRunning = true
        Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS)
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        //Creating new thread for my service
        //Always write your long running tasks in a separate thread, to avoid ANR
        Thread(Runnable {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                }
                val currentForegroundApp = getForegroundApp()
                val currentApp = currentForegroundApp.first
                if (currentApp != lastApp) {
                    // New app on front
                    lastApp = currentApp
                    println("Current App $lastApp")
                }
            }
        }).start()
        return START_STICKY
    }

    // Must Have Usage Access Permission
    fun getForegroundApp(): Pair<String, UsageStats> {
        var currentApp = "NULL"
        var currentAppInfo: UsageStats? = null
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            val usm = this.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE) as UsageStatsManager
            val time = System.currentTimeMillis()
            val appList =
                    usm.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, time - 1000 * 1000, time)
            if (appList != null && appList.size > 0) {
                val mySortedMap: SortedMap<Long, UsageStats> =
                        TreeMap<Long, UsageStats>()
                for (usageStats in appList) {
                    mySortedMap.put(usageStats.lastTimeUsed, usageStats)
                }
                if (mySortedMap != null && !mySortedMap.isEmpty()) {
                    currentAppInfo = mySortedMap[mySortedMap.lastKey()]!!
                    currentApp = mySortedMap[mySortedMap.lastKey()]!!.packageName
                }
            }
        } else {
            val am = this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
            val tasks = am.runningAppProcesses
            currentApp = tasks[0].processName
        }
        return Pair(currentApp.split(".").last(), currentAppInfo!!)
    }
    [...]
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I assume what you want isn't possible, because it has all sorts of security implications if apps can arbitrarily monitor what's happening inside completely unrelated apps. Aside from trying to open an app again and hoping it restores its state, you *might* be able to do something with capturing implicit intents and resending them - but even if that works, it's probably not going to put you back in "the same place" in an app if the user's done any navigation

Comment: Yes, the best thing I could find is using uiautomator to get a xml schema of the app, but even then, it is very difficult to actually find what the user is watching.